# TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_reactNative.Image.propTypes.source')

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native, expo

After upgrading to **Expo 46**, suddenly I started seeing these errors. I have searched on them, but did not find a solution so far. The app doesn't start anymore, it directly shows these errors.

Any ideas?

```
 ERROR  TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_reactNative.Image.propTypes.source')
Error: Unable to resolve module ./http://192.168.xx.xx:19000/index.ts from C:\xx/.:

None of these files exist:
  * http:\192.168.xx.xx:19000\index.ts(.native|.android.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.android.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx|.android.js|.native.js|.js|.android.jsx|.native.jsx|.jsx|.android.json|.native.json|.json|.android.svg|.native.svg|.svg|.android.cjs|.native.cjs|.cjs)
  * http:\192.168.xx.xx:19000\index.ts\index(.native|.android.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.android.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx|.android.js|.native.js|.js|.android.jsx|.native.jsx|.jsx|.android.json|.native.json|.json|.android.svg|.native.svg|.svg|.android.cjs|.native.cjs|.cjs)
    at ModuleResolver.resolveDependency (C:\xx\node_modules\metro\src\node-haste\DependencyGraph\ModuleResolution.js:136:15)
    at DependencyGraph.resolveDependency (C:\xx\node_modules\metro\src\node-haste\DependencyGraph.js:231:43)
    at C:\xx\node_modules\metro\src\lib\transformHelpers.js:129:24
    at Server._resolveRelativePath (C:\xx\node_modules\metro\src\Server.js:1137:12)
    at async Server.requestProcessor [as _processBundleRequest] (C:\xx\node_modules\metro\src\Server.js:464:37)
    at async Server._processRequest (C:\xx\node_modules\metro\src\Server.js:420:9)
 ERROR  Invariant Violation: "main" has not been registered. This can happen if:
* Metro (the local dev server) is run from the wrong folder. Check if Metro is running, stop it and restart it in the current project.
* A module failed to load due to an error and `AppRegistry.registerComponent` wasn't called
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue by divide and conquer strategy.

Commenting out every component and uncommenting them step by step until I found the issue.

In my case it was one of my plugins `react-native-qrcode-svg`, which needed to be updated in order to support the `Expo 46 upgrade`.